# Таблица рекордов

Tags: php, mysql

Как создать таблицу рекордов при помощи PHP и MySQL к Flash игре? таблица рекордов должна быть не в flash объекте а в новой странице. Участники Flash портала должы видеть и свои и чужие результаты.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Гхм... А в чем проблема-то?
 - заносите в БД рекорд (из flash)
 - на странице: подключаетесь к БД
 - делаете запрос к БД с упорядочиванием по очкам
 - затем перебираете строки результата, выводя данные
Все, что надо - [функции работы с mySQL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.mysql.php).

Answer (score 0):

Знаете, Ваш вопрос из серии "Как сделать такой сайт, чтобы много клевой музычки и клипов было, красивый такой, и чтоб в день сто тыщ заходило бы?".

Страница, на которой отображаются данные из таблицы - вещь настолько суперглобальная, что может быть прикручена к любому источнику данных, будь то Ваш флэш-объект, либо база секретных данных ЦРУ. Так что мой совет таков - пока изучите элементарную матчасть,а затем уже будете понимать, как прикручивать одно к другому.

Comment: не кипятись, @void! ... человек может быть создает свою ферму :)